# Can I apply for an Italian seasonal work visa while in Italy?

Tags: schengen-visas, work, south-africa, south-african-citizens

I am a South African citizen; I am looking for a seasonal job in Italy. If I am on holiday in Italy and find a job while there, will I have to return to South Africa to apply for the worker's visa from RSA? Or would it be possible to apply in Italy for the visa, or would I have to come back to South Africa anyway?

Comment: Have you researched the different types of visa available and do you have one in mind? It's not obvious to me that there would be. In particular, how long would your total stay be?

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't

[La Polizia di stato](https://www.poliziadistato.it/articolo/10718) states :

> Foreign workers must obtain the required visa from an Italian consulate in their country of origin or residence.

---

> Or would it be possible to apply in Italy for the visa

There are no Italian consulates in Italy and visas aren't issued on the country soil

---

You would be tempted to apply for a residence permit, but this again isn't a possibility, as you aren't allowed to reside on the basis of a tourist visa.

You need the relevant national D visa and also the relevant work authorization to be allowed to work in Italy and this can only be done from South Africa